# Android Remote Database No Data Insert

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am making an sample application where i can add data to my online(localhost) database which uses WAMP server, I have written an HTML form code to insert the data into DB to check wether the data is inserting to Table and it was a success.
So i wrote a sample code for android to insert the data using android, I am facing no force-closes, no error but the data is not getting inserted
here is all of my code

Form.Html

```html
<html>
<body>
 <form action = "submit.php" method="post">
  <fieldset >
  Question : <br>
  <textarea type="text" name="question" style="height: 100px ;width:800px"> </textarea> <br><br>
  Option 1 : <br>
  <input type="text" name="option1" style="height: 50px ;width:800px"> <br><br>
  Option 2 : <br>
  <input type="text" name="option2" style="height: 50px ;width:800px"> <br><br>
  Option 3 : <br>
  <input type="text" name="option3" style="height: 50px ;width:800px"> <br><br>
  Option 4 : <br>
  <input type="text" name="option4" style="height: 50px ;width:800px"> <br><br>
  Answer :<br>
  <input type="text" name="answer" style="height: 50px ;width:800px"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 40px ;width:800px">
  </fieldset>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHPScript

```html
<?php
//
$response = array();

if(!empty($_POST['question']) && !empty($_POST['option1']) && !empty($_POST['option2']) && !empty($_POST['option3']) && !empty($_POST['option4']) && !empty($_POST['answer'])){
 $question = $_POST['question'];
 $option1 = $_POST['option1'];
 $option2 = $_POST['option2'];
 $option3 = $_POST['option3'];
 $option4 = $_POST['option4'];
 $answer = $_POST['answer'];
 // import db connection variables
 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
 // connecting to mysql
 $db= new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
 // query for insertion
 $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `questions`(Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, Answer) VALUES ('$question','$option1','$option2','$option3','$option4','$answer')";
 // check 

 if ($db->query($insertQuery) == TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $insertQuery . "<br>" . $db->error;
 }
 $db->close();

}else{
  // import db connection variables
 require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
 // connecting to mysql
 $db= new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
 // query for insertion
 $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `questions`(Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, Answer) VALUES ('error','error','error','error','error','error')";
 // check 

 if ($db->query($insertQuery) == TRUE) {
     echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $insertQuery . "<br>" . $db->error;
 }
 $db->close();
}

?>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package library.danaraddi.com.myapplication;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpPost httpPost;
    private HttpResponse httpResponse;
    private List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairsList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // JSON parser class

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // importing button
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new SubmitData().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    class SubmitData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/CPSScripts/submit");
            nameValuePairsList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("question", "question"));
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option1", "option1"));
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option2", "option2"));
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option3", "option3"));
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option4", "option4"));
            nameValuePairsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", "answer"));

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairsList));
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.i("Response", httpResponse.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exception" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exception" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exception" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

PS : I have used .php and without extension too but the same result, and issues internet permission in my manifest

here is my Log.d

```
01-24 02:52:02.123    1925-1952/library.danaraddi.com.myapplication I/Response﹕ org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b30ee4d0
```